# Getting prefix as argument

Tags: debugging, interactive, message, prefix-argument

With this function, I get the error

```
test: Wrong type argument: stringp, 2
```

Is it good to pass prefix this way?  Thought that the argument `prefix` would be filled up with the prefix value.

```
(defun test (prefix)
  "TODO"
  (interactive "P")
  (message prefix)
  (message "Test"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lisp
(defun foo (raw num)
  (interactive "P\np")
  (message "RAW: %S, Numeric: %S" raw num))
```

Now try `M-x foo` with different prefix args.  The message will tell you how `interactive` handles `P` and `p`.

---

Your error is from function `message`, which `C-h f` will tell you expects a string as its first arg. Your first call to `message` calls it with whatever you used as the raw prefix argument.

`M-x set-variable RET debug-on-error RET t` enters the debugger when an error is raised, so you can see directly what your problem is.

---

Read about prefix arguments. In the Elisp manual (`C-h i m elisp`), `i prefix argument` takes you to node [Prefix Command Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html), which tells you all about it.

And if you're going to write Elisp code you owe it to yourself to read the manual **An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp**, also available with `C-h i`.

Comment: Read it.  I did not know one can pass `raw` and `num` for tho same prefix argument.  For interpreting prefix argument, I find that the raw prefix argument is better to work with.

Comment: Could I then use a condition such as `(cond ((equal raw '(4)) (statements for no C-u condition)`?

Comment: If it is equal to `'(4)`, then there *was* a `C-u` prefix. But why not elaborate your function in the light of your findings and try out the `cond`? Just use `(message "No C-u")` for the consequent e.g. It would be quicker to try out dozens of variations in the time that you are waiting for an answer here (which might never come).

Comment: You are right of course but was more interested in criticism.  Although I made things to work, experienced ones might suggest better ways than my crude test implementation.

Comment: Why is it that you use raw and num without specifying them as optional function arguments?. I think the correct way to pass prefix arguments is to declare them optional. But I do not know exactly why that is so.

Comment: There's no connection between an argument being optional and it being provided as a prefix argument - none.

Comment: @Drew I am trying to understand the implication of an argument being mandatory or optional, upon their setting within an interactive clause.  Been quite a headache that have not been able to figure out yet.

Comment: The only implication of an arg being mandatory or optional is for calling the function. It it's mandatory then omitting it raises an error; otherwise, no error. That's all.

Comment: You are right, but have difficulty with the use of the prefix argument.  One ran call an interactive function with the prefix argument (with `C-u`) or without (with `M-x`).  Would this mean that a prefix argument to the function has to be optional?  I could put another question if you like.

Comment: Using a prefix arg does not necessarily pass an argument to the function. A prefix arg is not necessarily an arg to the function, and vice versa. And again, a prefix arg need not be optional. And you can use `C-u` with `M-x`. I suggest you read the Emacs manual about prefix args. Start by `C-h k C-u`. A prefix arg is used (*can* be used) by the following command. It is not necessarily associate with any argument to that function. You can think of it as a global variable, if you like - the function has access to it, but it need not be one of the function's *arguments*.